# CheckMarx FLS Create/Update Vulnerability in Salesforce Apex Code

Tags: apex, security, fls, crud

I need help in fixing below vulnerabilities found in CheckMarx scan.

**Scenario:**

I have written a trigger on FeedItem object.

This trigger will archive the FeedItem into custom object ArchivedFeedItem__c.

Whenever user posts chatter post, the post should be archived to a custom object.

This trigger will use handler class

**FLS/CRUD permissions on ArchivedFeedItem__c:** System Administrator only have access. No other user have FLS/CRUD permissions on this custom object.

So the handler class to be executed in system mode and without enforcing FLS/CRUD

**Custom Object ArchivedFeedItem__c.object file**
[ArchivedFeedItem__c.object](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ChatterCompliance/blob/master/objects/ArchivedFeedItem__c.object)

**Trigger code:**

```
trigger FeedItemCM on FeedItem (after insert) {
FeedItemHandlerCM.upsertArchivedFeedItem(trigger.new);
```

}

**Handler Class Code:**

```
public class FeedItemHandlerCM {
public static void upsertArchivedFeedItem(List<FeedItem> fiList) {
    List<ArchivedFeedItem__c> li = new List<ArchivedFeedItem__c>();
    ArchivedFeedItem__c tmp;
        for (FeedItem f : fiList){
            tmp = new ArchivedFeedItem__c();                 
            if(f.BestCommentId!=null) {
                tmp.BestCommentId__c            = f.BestCommentId;
            }
            if(f.Body!=null) {
                tmp.Body__c                     = f.Body;
            }
            tmp.CommentCount__c             = f.CommentCount;
            tmp.Created_By__c               = f.CreatedById;
            tmp.CreatedDate__c              = f.CreatedDate;
            tmp.FeedItemId__c               = f.Id;
            tmp.FullArchivedCommentList__c  = (f.CommentCount == 0);
            tmp.HasContent__c               = f.HasContent;
            tmp.HasFeedEntity__c            = f.HasFeedEntity;
            tmp.HasLink__c                  = f.HasLink;
            tmp.HasVerifiedComment__c       = f.HasVerifiedComment;
            tmp.Inserted_By__c              = (f.InsertedById != null) ? f.InsertedById : f.CreatedById ;
            tmp.isDeleted__c                = f.IsDeleted;
            tmp.IsRichText__c               = f.IsRichText;
            tmp.LastEditBy__c             = f.LastEditById;
            tmp.LastEditDate__c             = f.LastEditDate;
            tmp.LikeCount__c                = f.LikeCount;
            if(f.LinkUrl!=null) {
                tmp.LinkUrl__c                  = f.LinkUrl;
            }
            tmp.ParentId__c                 = f.ParentId;
            if(f.RelatedRecordId!=null) {
                tmp.RelatedRecordId__c          = f.RelatedRecordId;
            }
            tmp.Revision__c                 = f.Revision;
            tmp.Status__c                   = f.Status;
            tmp.Title__c                    = f.Title;
            tmp.Type__c                     = f.Type;
            li.add(tmp);
        }

        if (!li.isEmpty()){
            upsert li;
        }  


}
```

}

**CheckMarx Report Summary**

Vulnerability Type-------------Occurrences------------------Severity

PAA APEX FLS Create------------24---------------------------High

PAA APEX FLS Update------------24---------------------------High

PAA APEX FLS Create Partial----1----------------------------High

PAA APEX FLS Update Partial----1----------------------------High

Total issues 50: one for each field and type of operation(insert/update)

**One Sample Issue details taken from CheckMarx Scan Report(All other 49 issues are similar)**

---

**Issue Details Start in Report**

**PAA APEX FLS Create\Path 1:**

Severity:   **High**

Result State:   **To Verify**

Source File: V1/src/classes/FeedItemHandlerCM.cls

Destination File:   V1/src/classes/FeedItemHandlerCM.cls

Line    9   44

Object  bestcommentid__c    li

Code Snippet

File Name   V1/src/classes/FeedItemHandlerCM.cls

Method  public static void upsertArchivedFeedItem(List fiList) {

```
....
```

9. **tmp.BestCommentId__c            = f.BestCommentId;**

....
44.                  **upsert li;**

**Issue Details End in report**

---

If I enfore FLS/CRUD using stripInaccessible,

```
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPSERTABLE, li);
upsert securityDecision.getRecords();
```

Users are unable to post a chatter post and they are receivig below error as they don't have FLS/CRUD permissions on custom object.

**Apex trigger FeedItemCM caused an unexpecte exception, contact your administrator:
FeedItemCM: execution of AfterInsert
System.NoAccessException: No access to entity Class.System.Security.stripInaccessible: line 15, column 1**

**Is this handler class or DML upsert really vulnerable?**

**How to fix the checkmarx issue without giving FLS/CRUD permissions to all profiles?**

**Is it false positive? If it is, then how can you say?**

Appreciate your help.
.

Comment: Since the goal of the requirement requires the code to operate against objects and fields that the contextual user may not have access to, you are forced to ignore CRUD/FLS in order to realize the requirement. As such this is a Checkmarx false positive and must be addressed by explaining the scenario in your submission documentation and, as per the linked Q/A, it is best to comment the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much Phil for quick help on this.  Your two responses helped very much! Appeciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal of the requirement requires the code to operate against objects and fields that the contextual user may not have access to, you are forced to ignore CRUD/FLS in order to realize the requirement. As such this is a Checkmarx false positive and must be addressed by explaining the scenario in your submission documentation.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/293786/50252) covers how you can also best to comment the relevant code to help the Salesforce Security Team navigate the report from Checkmarx.